# Owin/NancyFx Trailing Slash on Root Path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, nancy

I have an Owin/NancyFx single-page application using AngularJs and UI Router.

Its hosted in IIS7 and for the most part everything is working. However there is one annoying issue with the root path that I can't seem to solve.

I would like a trailing slash on the root path, something like:

`http://myserver.internaldomain.com/myapp/`

This way when UI Router goes to handle the hashbang routing, all urls will look like:

`http://myserver.internaldomain.com/myapp/#/mySpaRoute`

However, I can't seem to get a trailing slash to append, so instead my URL looks like:

`http://myserver.internaldomain.com/myapp#/mySpaRoute`

I have tried to create an Owin middleware the looks at the URL and redirects if there's a missing `/` at the end. This works for all routes that are handled by the WebApi but not NancyFx. That seems reasonable since NancyFx takes over routing early to handle rendering its views.

Next I tried a NancyFx `BeforeRequest` pipeline lambda to do the same thing, interrogate the URL and append a `/` as needed. This however resulted in a redirect loop. The request would come in to the pipeline as: `http://example.com/app`, and then redirect to: `http://example.com/app/`, however at the next pipeline execution, the trailing `/` would be stripped and the pipeline handler would redirect again -- this is where the loop occured.

So I guess simply, how do I make NancyFx add a trailing `/` to the end of my routes?

**Update:**

Went to lunch, talked to the [duck](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) a bit, updated all the assemblies, then decided that its just the root get path that I really need to append the `/` to make hashbang routing look decent:

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    // note this works fine when running from localhost, but when running
    // as an application in IIS, a redirect loop occurs
    public HomeModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = _ =>
        {
            var requestUri = new Uri(Request.Url);
            if (!requestUri.AbsoluteUri.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                var targetUri = requestUri.ToString() + "/";
                return Response.AsRedirect(targetUri);
            }

            const string view = "views/home.cshtml";
            var model = new { Title = Constants.ApplicationTitle };
            return View[view, model];
        }
    }
}
```

*Annnnnnd* Redirect loop.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately this appears to have been caused by the `Uri` class. The `Uri` class does a very good job of removing trailing slashes in many cases. This means that I was, essentially, fixing any "malformed" urls by creating a new `Uri` out of them. Then I was breaking these nice Uri's by appending a `/` to them. On redirect the newly cast `Uri` would remove my extraneous `/`, then fail the `if` statement and the process would begin again, hence by redirect loop.

To fix the issue, I instead used the `System.Web.HttpContextBase` property provided in the owin environment context and checked the `Request.Url` property which seems to be the original requested Url with little or no post-processing.

These changes were made in my `EnforceTrailingSlashMiddleware` that I had written earlier. Here is the invoke method:

```
public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    var httpContext = context.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as System.Web.HttpContextBase;
    if (httpContext != null && httpContext.Request != null && httpContext.Request.Url != null)
    {
        var path = httpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
        /*
         formatter is a class ("SlashFormatter") with two methods:

         "ShouldAppendSlash" which takes a path string and returns a boolean
              (whether or not a slash should be appended)

         "AppendSlash" which takes a string, safely appends a slash and
               then returns the modified string.
        */
        if (formatter.ShouldAppendSlash(path))
        {
            var url = formatter.AppendSlash(path);
            context.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }

    await Next.Invoke(context);
}
```

Comment: this seems like a bad solution because it depends on IIS... have you found any other solution?

Comment: Using context.Request.Uri will give you the same value without the hard System.Web dependency. It's also the middleware way of doing it.